# Entity Framework select multiple columns and return the one that is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am building a URL using variables from entities. I would like to select a user record based on ID and return either the mobile or landline, default mobile but if it is blank then landline. Below is my current code:

```
var phone = context.Addresses
                .Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID)
                .Select(x => x.Mobile)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var url = String.Format(Urls.CreateClientUrl,
                settings.EntityID,
                settings.ClinicID,
                UserID.Value,
                clientID,
                client.FirstName,
                client.LastName,
                email,
                phone);
```

Obviously this work for phone and returns the string mobile but if it is empty, I would like to return the string phone. Below is what I have tried:

```
                var phone = context.Addresses
                .Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID)
                .Select(x => new { x.Mobile, x.Phone })
                .FirstOrDefault();

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var url = String.Format(Urls.CreateClientUrl,
                settings.EntityID,
                settings.ClinicID,
                UserID.Value,
                clientID,
                client.FirstName,
                client.LastName,
                email,
                phone);
```

This returns both strings. I would like to only get the string Phone in the event that mobile is empty.

I have followed a few other threads in SO but my limited knowledge is only returning broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "blank" and "empty" you mean `null`, you can use null propagation operator

```
string phone = "123";
string mobile = null;

string mobileThenPhone = mobile ?? phone;
```

You can even use it multiple times

```
string mobileThenPhoneThenDefault = mobile ?? phone ?? "No contact info";
```

So in your case e.g

```
string.Format(..., mobile ?? phone ?? "Some default")
```

You can't always use it in a LINQ query that is being translated to SQL but it looks like that doesn't apply here because you've downloaded the data by the time you're formatting it. If you do hit a "cannot contain a null propagation" error in an EF query you can either look to swap it for a more typical `something == null ? otherthing : something`, or download both things from the db and evaluate it for null in c#

---

If by "blank" and "empty" you mean `""` or "contains only whitespace" you can use

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mobile) ? phone : mobile
```

It's not quite as compact as null propagation and you should avoid nesting it because, though possible, it gets unreadable pretty quickly:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mobile) ? )string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone) ? "default" : phone) : mobile
```

To tidy that up you could define an extension method on string:

```
static string IfBlank(this string test, string alternative){
  return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(test)?alternative:test;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
mobile.IfBlank(phone).IfBlank("default");
```

But beware if mobile is null you'll have to kick things off like this to avoid a crash:

```
(mobile??"").IfBlank(phone).IfBlank("default");
```

Comment: Thank you for that. So I declared two more variables, one for phone and one for mobileThenPhone. Then `var mobileThenPhone = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobile) ? phone : mobile;` Then I called the new variable in my URL

Comment: Yep, or you can skip the new variable and just use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobile) ? phone : mobile` straight in your url - looking closer at your code I can see the anonymous type in there - you can skip even creating any interim variables and just use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone.Mobile) ? phone.Phone : phone.Mobile`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var phone = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID).Select(x => x.Mobile ?? x.Phone).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var phone = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID).Select(x => x.Mobile).FirstOrDefault();
if (test == null || test == "")
{
    phone = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID).Select(x => x.Phone).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I did try your first example in my efforts but null propagation does not work in my case because something is always returned. Mobile returns an empty string if the db does not have a value.

Comment: You can check that with `if(test == "")` if returning empty string or even with `Convert.ToString(test)` which will return you empty string if test is `null`. See updated answer.